# Check Prime numbers as user input In Java

Tags: java

i am trying to check the user input whether it is a prime number or not. The below code is mine. what would be wrong here?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    int a;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter number to check : ");

    //sc.close();

    for (a = sc.nextInt(); a > 2;) {

        boolean isPrime = true;

        for (int b = 2; b < a; b++) {

            if (a % b == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
                //System.out.println(a + " is not a prime number");
                break;
            }

            if(isPrime) {
                System.out.println(a + " is a prime number");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why make us guess?

Comment: Why do you *think* something is wrong?

Comment: its looping with both printed lines

Answer (score 2):

Move your print statement(s) outside of the inner loop.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    int a;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter number to check : ");

    //sc.close();

    for (a = sc.nextInt(); a > 2;) {
        boolean isPrime = true;

        for (int b = 2; b < a; b++) {
            if (a % b == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(isPrime) {
            System.out.println(a + " is a prime number");
        } else {
            System.out.println(a + " is not a prime number");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the outer is still an endless loop as a never changes ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your program's only invocation of `sc.nextInt()` appears in the initialization clause of the outer loop.  The input is therefore read before the first iteration of that loop's body, and never again.  As a result, every iteration of the outer loop tests the same value of `a`, so you will therefore either loop infinitely or not at all.

Additionally, as @Gendarme noted in his answer, you have a `System.out.println()` inside your inner loop.  It should be lifted to the outer one, so that it only prints after all iterations of the inner one are complete and the final answer is therefore known.